# How can I refresh another page in Django?

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

Is there any way to refresh another page by clicking a button on the current page?
(any way for the server to send a packet that makes every browser on a certain URL page refresh itself)

```
example:

127.0.0.1:8000/main -> a page that has the button

127.0.0.1:8000/list -> a page I want to refresh
```

My desktop web browser is currently on `'/main'` and my laptop web browser is currently on `'/list'`.
How can I refresh my laptop web browser(to a newer version of the `'/list'` page) by clicking a button on the `'/main'` page on my desktop?

Is using websocket(like django-channels) the only way to do this work?

Comment: You could connect your app via websockets to the server and the server sends messages via those websockets to all connected clients. When receiving the message, your web application (= javascript) can update the current page using `location.reload()`. (This mechaism is completely independent of Django).

Comment: @Nechoj If I want to trigger the event from different django application, should I connect both applications via websockets to the server?( I want to send messages to application B when someone clicks a button on application A) Or how can I trigger the event(=server sends message to app B via websocket) from another app(app A)

Comment: If it is asymetric and you only need to trigger B from A, then only B needs connection via websocket. You could send a http POST when clicking button on A and the web server then sends the update message to B.